# Como salvar um gráfico ggplot sem perder a qualidade para Word e Power Point?

Tags: ggplot2, r

Estou tendo problemas para salvar os gráficos de maneira que: ou eles perdem a qualidade ou alteram suas dimensões em relação ao background da folha que o recebe.

Tentativa.1 <- Uma figura com dimensões de 15 x 13 eu transformei em 300DPI. Pedi então, que fosse width = 1772; Heigth = 1417 em PNG e depois em JPGE.
Ambos me deram uma figura que alterou as proporções de todos os "labs e titles" e ainda exibiu de uma figura meio opaca.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentativa 2 <- Reduzi drasticamente o tamanho para testar e deixei em 600 x 400.
As cores voltaram a ter melhor exibição (perderam a opacidade). Contudo, o gráfico estoura fácil a resolução quando se amplia. E do mesmo modo do anterior, os labs e titles foram alterado de escala (agora, parecem maiores que o size determinado).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentativa.3 <-  Por fim, salvei em formato pdf aproveitando os limites da página A4 e de duas forma: portrait e landscape.
Em ambos, a exibição via Adobe PFD software fica uma maravilha e certamente não estourou ora nenhuma ampliando ou diminuindo dentro do "zoom" do próprio software. As escalas de labs e titles tb não mudaram. Até aí tudo certo.
O problema foi na hora de exportar para word e powerpoint. As figuras perdem a qualidade na importação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As figuras que ilustrei acima são fieis aos dados originais e não aos dados que disponibilizo abaixo por solicitação de @Rui Barradas

```
structure(list(Grupo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L), .Label = c("TEPT", "TA", "TOC", "Controle"), class = "factor"), 
    ClusterB = c(9, 10, 12, 11, 17, 19, 2, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 
    9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 5, 6, 1, 2, 6, 1), ClusterC = c(4, 4, 5, 4, 
    8, 7, 3, 0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
    1), ClusterD = c(13, 18, 18, 19, 17, 10, 6, 8, 7, 11, 5, 
    10, 7, 14, 10, 14, 14, 14, 7, 8, 1, 2, 8, 1), ClusterE = c(15, 
    15, 16, 17, 17, 20, 8, 3, 5, 9, 7, 5, 6, 12, 13, 12, 12, 
    12, 6, 3, 5, 7, 4, 4), PCL.5.total = c(41, 47, 51, 51, 59, 
    56, 19, 14, 18, 28, 21, 22, 20, 39, 37, 39, 39, 39, 20, 20, 
    8, 13, 21, 7)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 77L, 
78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 
227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L), class = "data.frame")
```

segue o código de geração dos gráficos

```
compar = list(c("TEPT","TA"),c("TEPT","TOC"),c("TEPT","Controle"),
              c("TA","TOC"),c("TA","Controle"),c("TOC","Controle"))

sigs <- c("p < 0,05","p < 0,01","p < 0,001","ns","ns","ns")

cores <- scale_fill_manual(values = c("red","yellow","#007eff","green"))


box1 <- ggplot(PCLhead, aes(Grupo, ClusterB),color = "black") +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", size = 1, width = 0.1) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Grupo), show.legend = F) +
  labs(title = "Revivescência/Intrusão",x = "",
       y = "Escores", tag = "A") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold", color = "Black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, color = "black"),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 11),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold")) +
  geom_signif(comparisons = compar,
              textsize = 2.5,
              y_position = c(25,28,31,12,15,18),
              tip_length = c(0.2,0.05,
                             0.05,0.3,
                             0.4,0.05,
                             0.05,0.05,
                             0.2,0.05,
                             0.05,0.05),
              annotations = format(x = sigs)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,40),breaks = seq(0,40,5)) +
  cores

box1


box2 <- ggplot(PCLhead, aes(Grupo, ClusterC)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", size = 1, width = 0.1) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Grupo), show.legend = F) +
  labs(title = "Evitação ou Esquiva", x = "", y ="Escores", tag = "B") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold", color = "Black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, color = "black"),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 11),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,40),breaks = seq(0,40,5)) +
  geom_signif(comparisons = compar,
              textsize = 2.5,
              y_position = c(25,28,31,12,15,9),
              tip_length = c(0.2,0.9,
                             0.05,0.3,
                             0.4,0.05,
                             0.2,0.05,
                             0.2,0.05,
                             0.05,0.05),
              annotations = format(x = sigs)) +
  cores

box2


box3 <- ggplot(PCLhead, aes(Grupo, ClusterD)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", size = 1, width = 0.1) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Grupo), show.legend = F) +
  labs(title = "Alt. Neg. no Humor e Cognição",
       x = "",y ="Escores", tag = "C") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold", color = "Black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, color = "black"),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 11),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,40),breaks = seq(0,40,5)) +
  geom_signif(comparisons = compar,
              textsize = 2.5,
              y_position = c(30,33,36,17,20,23),
              tip_length = c(0.2,0.05,
                             0.05,0.25,
                             0.3,0.05,
                             0.1,0.05,
                             0.2,0.05,
                             0.05,0.05),
              annotations = format(x = sigs)) +
  cores

box3


box4 <- ggplot(PCLhead, aes(Grupo, ClusterE)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", size = 1, width = 0.1)+
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Grupo), show.legend = F)+
  labs(title = "Hipervigilância ou Hiperexcitabilidade",
       x = "", y = "Escores", tag = "D") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold", color = "Black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, color = "black"),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 11),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,40),breaks = seq(0,40,5)) +
  geom_signif(comparisons = compar,
              textsize = 2.5,
              y_position = c(29,32,35,17,20,23),
              tip_length = c(0.15,0.07,
                             0.05,0.2,
                             0.3,0.05,
                             0.2,0.05,
                             0.2,0.05,
                             0.05,0.05),
              annotations = format(x = sigs)) +
  cores

box4


box1_4 <- plot_grid(box1,box2,box3,box4, nrow = 2)
box1_4
```

> O que eu estou fazendo de errado ou não atentando nesse procedimento para que as figuras não ajustem automaticamente os tamanhos depois de salvas em alta resolução?

Comment: Faltam os dados e o código...

Comment: Ok @RuiBarradas, vou tentar compilar então com dput. Mas além de ser um data.frame grande. Ainda tem o fato de que são dados de certa forma, sigilosos. Não enviei de imediato pelo fato de pensei ser um problema ligado a um package ou função que desconheço. De todo modo, irei ver como faço um dput aqui de parte dos dados. pelo menos um head(). Em instante irei atualizar a pergunta!

Comment: @gleidsonmr, se seus dados são sigilosos, utilize alguma das bases inclusas no R, como a `mtcars`. Poste também o código que está usando para exportar os gráficos. Como dica geral: exporte como SVG (suponho que Word e Powerpoint suportam). Por fim, como está usando o pacote ggpubr, verifique a documentação da função 'ggexport'.

Comment: Se tiver usando o `ggsave` tente mudar o parâmetro `scale`. Até com png não ficou tão destorcido aqui.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoLagosta, eu confesso que não tenho o hábito de utilizar as funções de salvamento. Sempre tenho utilizado o próprio prompt de visualização dos plots. Ajusto no tamanho que necessito e depois "copy to clipboard". Desta vez o que foi novo nesse procedimento usual foi o fato de que tenho 4 gráficos em uma única visualização. Anteriormente não precisava visualizar tantos gráficos de uma vez.

Comment: Se precisa de imagens com qualidade e controle sobre o resultado final, exporte para formato vetorial. Basta escrever a linha uma vez e repetir os parâmetros sempre que precisar, automatizando o processo.

Answer (score 2):

As vezes plotar figuras a partir do R não é uma tarefa simples. É necessário paciência para verificação do melhor ajuste.

Inclusive há quem pule a etapa final de ajuste de plot para o uso de algum software de design, como o Photoshop.

Porém, eu uso uma técnica empírica para situações como esta sua. Eu estimo a proporção "ideal" (largura x altura) a partir da verificação a priori do Window no RStudio. Por exemplo:

> O Window mais alongado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> O Window achatado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Aumentando a altura e a largura do Window (ainda achatado).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Feito isto (tentativas prévias), eu tenho uma noção do meu argumentos `width` e `height`, para o plot.

Quanto ao código, realizei mudanças no seu ajuste de tema. Criei um tema global (`bold`), onde busquei deixar o texto mais nítido com o emprego do negrito. Também aumentei o argumento `textsize` do `geom_signif` de `2.5` para `4`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsignif)
library(cowplot)
# set tema
bold <- theme(
  plot.title   = element_text(face = "bold", colour = "black",
                              size = 11),
  axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", colour = "black",
                              size = 11),    
  axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", colour = "black",
                              size = 11),    
  axis.text.x  = element_text(face = "bold", colour = "black",
                              size = 10), 
  axis.text.y  = element_text(face = "bold", colour = "black",
                              size = 10),
  strip.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", colour = "black"),
  strip.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", colour = "black"))

box1 <- ggplot(PCLhead, aes(Grupo, ClusterB),color = "black") +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", size = 1, width = 0.1) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Grupo), show.legend = F) +
  labs(title = "Revivescência/Intrusão",x = "",
       y = "Escores", tag = "A") +
  geom_signif(comparisons = compar,
              textsize = 4,
              y_position = c(25,28,31,12,15,18),
              tip_length = c(0.2,0.05,
                             0.05,0.3,
                             0.4,0.05,
                             0.05,0.05,
                             0.2,0.05,
                             0.05,0.05),
              annotations = format(x = sigs), 
              color = "black") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 40),breaks = seq(0, 40, 5)) +
  cores + bold #

box2 <- ggplot(PCLhead, aes(Grupo, ClusterC)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", size = 1, width = 0.1) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Grupo), show.legend = F) +
  labs(title = "Evitação ou Esquiva", x = "", y ="Escores", tag = "B") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,40),breaks = seq(0,40,5)) +
  geom_signif(comparisons = compar,
              textsize = 4,
              y_position = c(25,28,31,12,15,9),
              tip_length = c(0.2,0.9,
                             0.05,0.3,
                             0.4,0.05,
                             0.2,0.05,
                             0.2,0.05,
                             0.05,0.05),
              annotations = format(x = sigs), color = "black") +
  cores + bold #

box3 <- ggplot(PCLhead, aes(Grupo, ClusterD)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", size = 1, width = 0.1) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Grupo), show.legend = F) +
  labs(title = "Alt. Neg. no Humor e Cognição",
       x = "",y ="Escores", tag = "C") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,40),breaks = seq(0,40,5)) +
  geom_signif(comparisons = compar,
              textsize = 4,
              y_position = c(30,33,36,17,20,23),
              tip_length = c(0.2,0.05,
                             0.05,0.25,
                             0.3,0.05,
                             0.1,0.05,
                             0.2,0.05,
                             0.05,0.05),
              annotations = format(x = sigs), color = "black") +
  cores + bold #

box4 <- ggplot(PCLhead, aes(Grupo, ClusterE)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", size = 1, width = 0.1)+
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Grupo), show.legend = F)+
  labs(title = "Hipervigilância ou Hiperexcitabilidade",
       x = "", y = "Escores", tag = "D") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,40),breaks = seq(0,40,5)) +
  geom_signif(comparisons = compar,
              textsize = 4,
              y_position = c(29,32,35,17,20,23),
              tip_length = c(0.15,0.07,
                             0.05,0.2,
                             0.3,0.05,
                             0.2,0.05,
                             0.2,0.05,
                             0.05,0.05),
              annotations = format(x = sigs), color = "black") +
  cores +
  bold

box1_4 <- plot_grid(box1,box2,box3,box4, nrow = 2) +
  theme(title = element_text(face = "bold"))
box1_4
ggsave(filename = "box1_4.png", box1_4,
       width = 10, height = 7, dpi = 500, units = "in", device='png')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Contudo ainda haveria mais um passo, que é a verificação no documento final. Sendo este crucial, no qual poderia te "forçar" a etapa de *save* (`ggsave`) para ajustes dos argumentos `width` e `height`.

Outra possível solução seria trabalhar com RMarkdown ou LaTex, onde, acredito, que você não terá problema com resolução no documento final.